# Sharepoint Content Type - Adding a new one

Tags: content-type

I am trying to add a content type for Risks and Issues based on the Task Content Type. When I go to web galleries and use the Content Type option to create the Risks and Issues Type I can select Task as the parent. The task type though does not have all the columns I have in the Content Type Task that I am using. There is no other Task Content Type available to choose as the parent. Is there a setting I need to use on the Task Content Type to ensure all the columns are visible when using the web gallery to set up a new content type?

Answer (score 0):

Before you add a custom content type, you usually create site columns that meet your needs. See http://SiteCollectionURL/_layouts/15/mngfield.aspx where you add custom site columns.